# Pandas: Turn a Column into a Table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that is actually two tables. Each row in the table is the row from table A and the row from table B, separated by '|'. Columns in each one are separated by ','.

This is a HUGE table (200 GB) so I need this done efficiently.

Sample data:

```
0.0,0|586,abc,6
0.4,2|416,efg,3
1.0,8|007,hik,1
```

I want to get table A as a pandas table, and table B as a separate pandas table.

Comment: What operations do you hope to perform on this? Unless you've got a massive machine, for a raw 200gb of that format, you should allow at least 600-700gb of RAM for in-memory dataframes (and that's probably very conservative... maybe even 1tb before you get started).

Comment: I have a massive machine.

Comment: Okay... got at least a few hundred gig ram to start with?

Comment: Yes, I do, and the size is about 100 GB raw.

Comment: What do you intend to do with those dataframes after?

Answer (score 2):

"This is a HUGE table (200 GB) so I need this done efficiently." - then don't use `pandas`.

If you must, you could first read the data in as a single dataframe:

```
  df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, sep='[,|]')
```

Then separate the data as required:

```
  df1 = df.iloc[:, 0:3]
  df2 = df.iloc[:, 3:5]
  del df
```

This deals with the separation, and only loads the data once, but you should look into a different tool for something of that size...

Comment: Why wouldn't you use pandas? Would core python handle this better?

Comment: @Datanovice - to be fair, if you have enough RAM, then you could use pandas. I think a more conventional `big data` tool would be appropriate, e.g. spark.